# Gradle tests not found on build after version update

Tags: gradle, groovy, junit, intellij-plugin

I'm having a problem with a gradle build.

Here is my build.gradle file :

```
import groovy.xml.XmlSlurper
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def property(String key) { return project.findProperty(key).toString() }

static def definedInPluginXml(String key) {
    File pluginXmlFile = new File('src/main/resources/META-INF/plugin.xml')
    def idea = new XmlSlurper().parse(pluginXmlFile)
    return idea."$key"
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '1.5.3'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.changelog' version '1.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.changelog'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.9'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}

// See https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/
intellij {
    version = '2022.1'
    plugins = ['java', 'com.intellij.java', 'org.intellij.groovy']
}

/**
 * Refreshes the plugin.xml file for deployment
 */
String ideaMinVersion = property("ideaMinVersion")
String ideaMaxVersion = property("ideaMaxVersion")
String pluginVersion = property("version")
patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes = changelog.get(pluginVersion).toHTML()
    version = pluginVersion
    sinceBuild = ideaMinVersion
    untilBuild = ideaMaxVersion
}

test {
    useJUnit()
    filter{
        includeTestsMatching "fr.nereide.*"
    }
}

tasks {
    runIde {
        jvmArgs("-Xmx2048m")
    }
}

/**
 * Config for changelog Plugin
 */
changelog {
    itemPrefix = "-"
    keepUnreleasedSection = false
    unreleasedTerm = "[Unreleased]"
    groups = ["Added", "Changed", "Deprecated", "Removed", "Fixed", "Security"]
}

/**
 * Generates the updatePlugin.xml files used for the repo.
 */
task generateUpdatePluginXml {
    //...
}

/**
 * Adds tests on build
 */
buildPlugin {
    dependsOn 'test'
    dependsOn 'generateUpdatePluginXml'
    tasks.findByName('generateUpdatePluginXml').mustRunAfter 'patchPluginXml'
}
```

And here are the version infos :

```
./gradlew --version                                                                                                                                                
Welcome to Gradle 7.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Faster incremental Java compilation
 - Easier source set configuration in the Kotlin DSL

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.1/release-notes.html


------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2021-06-14 14:47:26 UTC
Revision:     989ccc9952b140ee6ab88870e8a12f1b2998369e

Kotlin:       1.4.31
Groovy:       3.0.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.15 (Oracle Corporation 11.0.15+3)
OS:           Linux 5.15.32-1-MANJARO amd64
```

I updated the following dependencies :

- org.jetbrains.intellij from 1.1.4 to 1.5.3
- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all: from 2.5.14 to 3.0.9

Also updated
`intellij { version = '2022.1' } // from 2021.2`

Before the updates, the tests were found just fine.
Now, after the updates, i get the following error :

> Task :test FAILED
> Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: fr.nereide.*

And i'm kind of a gradle noob, it's very unclear to me how it works, i find the docs superficial.

So here are my questions :

- Is there a simple way to launch all tests (without any restrictions)
- Do i have to add the `@Test` decorator ? It wasn't necessary before updates, and doesn't change much with curent versions.
- Where could i find the docs and informations i could have used to find the migrations infos on the packages i updated
- Is there some ressource like Gradle for Dummies that someone could actually recommend ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue, it's been a while i know.
i replaced `useJUnit()` with `useJUnitPlatform()`
and

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.9'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
}
```

with

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.9'
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.8.2')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine'
}
```